# Making multiplication into ColumnDef field ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Is possible to make operation inside the field?
I need to multiply CostoUnitario with Qta, and display it in the TOTALE column

This is my array.In the ng grid, the user will insert values (I setted 4 field just to try).
Everything works fine elsewhere, I can get the result I want, but I need the field Totale to show the multiplication between CostoUnitario and Qta. (It's an invoice.)

```
     $scope.myData = [{Numero:'',Descrizione:'',CostoUnitario:'10',Qta:'1',Totale:''},
                  {Numero:'',Descrizione:'',CostoUnitario:'90',Qta:'1',Totale:''},
                  {Numero:'',Descrizione:'',CostoUnitario:'',Qta:'',Totale:''},
                  {Numero:'',Descrizione:'',CostoUnitario:'',Qta:'',Totale:''},
                  {Numero:'',Descrizione:'',CostoUnitario:'',Qta:'',Totale:''},
                  {Numero:'',Descrizione:'',CostoUnitario:'',Qta:'',Totale:''}
  ];           
  $scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData', 
    enableCellSelection: true,
    enableCellEdit: true,
    enableRowSelection: false,
    columnDefs: [{field: 'Numero', displayName: 'Numero', enableCellEdit: true},
      {field:'Descrizione', displayName:'Descrizione'},
      {field: 'CostoUnitario', displayName: 'Costo Unitario', enableCellEdit: true},
      {field: 'Qta', displayName: 'Qta', enableCellEdit: true},
      {field: 'CostoUnitario*Qta', displayName: 'Totale', enableCellEdit: false}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. I attached a function to each row in the data and referenced it in `field` key for the `Totale` column.

Here's the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xvOeNlKtXVwxlPYSDQ0B?p=preview)

```
columnDefs: [{field: 'Numero', displayName: 'Numero', enableCellEdit: true},
      {field:'Descrizione', displayName:'Descrizione'},
      {field: 'CostoUnitario', displayName: 'Costo Unitario', enableCellEdit: true},
      {field: 'Qta', displayName: 'Qta', enableCellEdit: true},
      {field: 'getTotale()', displayName: 'Totale', enableCellEdit: false}
    ]
```

...

```
angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(row) {
    row.getTotale = function() {
      return row.CostoUnitario * row.Qta;
    };
  });
```

Comment: AWWWW Thank you very much!!! I was stuck on this problem by a week! I owe you one!

Comment: I don't have $scope as I am working with Angular 1.5 components which have isolated scope already. Therefore, to make it work I had to declare my function in my controller and then put the following in columnDefs
`cellTemplate: '<div>{{grid.appScope.$parent.$ctrl.calculateDisplayValue(row)}}</div>'` My function looks at the values in row and performs some calculations and returns the value that should be displaying the cell.
Hope this helps someone.